# An erroneous way to derive sampling with replacement

Tags: combinatorics

So sampling $k$ elements out of $n$ elements with replacement is ${n+k-1}\choose{k}$, and I understand how to derive it. But when I first approached this question, my reasoning is that it is the same as having $k$ copies of $n$ elements each and selecting $k$ out of them. Therefore, it should be ${k \cdot n} \choose {k}$. Why would this derivation not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is flawed because your method allows you to distinguish between elements of the same type.

Consider for example that we want to sample (with replacement) $2$ elements out of $\{0,1\}$. Clearly, there are $\binom{2 + 2 - 1}{2}  = 3$ ways to do so.

By your approach, we would count the number of ways to pick (without replacement) $2$ elements out of $\{0_1, 0_2, 1_1, 1_2\}$. However, that means that we treat $\{0_1, 1_1\}, \{0_2, 1_1\}, \{0_1, 1_2\}, \{0_2, 1_2\}$ as four distinct ways, even though they should all be considered the same. And indeed, if we treat them as the same, we get our original answer of $3$.